# Using 00:00:00 in Laravel controller gives undefined variable error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a question concerning a validation function i am working on. What  I wanna do is to match the time input of the user with the existing opening times of the respective product.

In the Controller i have the following variable:

```
  $proOpening = ProgramsOpening::where('program_fk', '=', $proId)
                ->where('from','<>','00:00:00')
                ->where('to','<>','00:00:00')
                ->get();
```

That gets me all opening hours if they exist, there are also opening hours that don't have a specific opening time.

In the view I use a foreach loop to display the respective opening hours in a table:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="oeffnungszeiten">
<table class="table table-striped">
        @foreach($proOpening as $open)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$open->days}}: </td>
                <td>{{$open->from}} - {{$open->to}}{{trans("frontend.programmDetails_o_clock")}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach



    @if ($language == "de")
        @if(!empty($proDesc->program_time))
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{!! $proDesc->program_time !!} </td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @else
            @if(!empty($proDesc->program_time_en))
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">{!! $proDesc->program_time_en !!} </td>
                </tr>
            @endif
    @endif
</table>
</div>
```

In the corresponding Javascript i do validation with a alert pop up if the input of time doesn't match the opening hours from the database:

```
var time_open_begin = "{{$open->from}}";
var time_open_end = "{{$open->to}}";
//Validation
if( !$('#opening_from ').val() ) {
    document.getElementById("warn_msg").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>{{trans("frontend.programdetails_error_time")}}</div>";
    error = true;
}  else if ($('#opening_from').val() < time_open_begin || $('#opening_from').val() > time_open_end  ) {
    document.getElementById("warn_msg").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>Deine Auswahl stimmt nicht mit den Öffnungszeiten überein</div>";
    error = true;
}
```

My problem is the following, that all events that are set with 00:00:00 are treated as undefined variable. If I remove the

```
->where('from','<>','00:00:00')
->where('to','<>','00:00:00')
```

condition in the controller, 00:00:00 opening hours are display and validation never goes through.

> Undefined variable: open (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\public\laravel\resources\views\frontend\programs\programmDetails.blade.php)

Any ideas for that?

Comment: which value you want here `var time_open_begin = "{{$open->from}}";` ?

Comment: `$open` is block level variable in `@foreach($proOpening as $open)`, can't be use outside foreach

Comment: you need to pass like this : var time_open_begin = "{!! $open->from !!}";
                var time_open_end = "{!! $open->to !!}";

Comment: @ Prashant Prajapati, thanks for your comment, but your propasal appears to be only a syntax thing that doesn't affect my question at all

Comment: @ Machavity - i considered your comment, which raised another question, why is it possible to access var time_open_begin = "{{$open -> from }}" if the condition from the controller is met, the undefined variable appears only if from equals 00:00:00 which is one condition of the database

Comment: I found a solution by myself, won't spare to let you know. Apparently you can use blade-laravel-syntax in the script-part, too. So by using an @if conditon with isset solves the problem of the undefined variable, if the database value has the value 00:00:00:

Comment: @if (isset($open->from))
                        var time_open_begin = "{{$open->from}}";
                        var time_open_end = "{{ $open->to}}";


                         if ($('#opening_from').val() < time_open_begin || $('#opening_from').val() > time_open_end  ) {

Comment: document.getElementById("warn_msg").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>{{trans("frontend.programdetails_error_msg_time")}}</div>";
                                    error = true;
                        }


                    @endif